# File Share Witness DAG Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

Can anyone please explain how I correct this or if I need to...

I have a Exchange Server x2 server DAG, and 1 FSW.

All seems to be working but when I first set this up I tried to make a DC a FSW, I had issues so I recreated the FSW on one of the CAS boxes.

If I run the following cmdlets I get the following:

[PS] C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Scripts>cluster *****DAG.******.local res
Listing status for all available resources:

Resource             Group                Node            Status

---

File Share Witness (\******dc01.********.local*****.*******.local) Cluster Group        *****DAG     02 Online

Which shows that the DC01 is still being thought of a FSW
If I look in the EMC I clearly see that the FSW is on the CAS box.
If I run the following you can see:
[PS] C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Scripts>Get-databaseavailabilitygroup -Identity ********DAG -Status | fl

RunspaceId                             : 07430ef7-6e85-4d7a-a465-8b3cd34c36b9
Name                                   : ******DAG
Servers                                : {*********DAG02, ******DAG01}
WitnessServer                          : ********cas01.*******.local
WitnessDirectory                       : C:\FSW_DAG

Is this an issue? as also I cannot seem to browse to the file share witness folder using the full path  \server\dagname, I get an error you do not have permissions.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638104.aspx) document? In addition, please take a look at [this](http://www.thecabal.org/2009/12/busting-the-exchange-trusted-subsystem-myth/).